# PPA removal problems

Tags: updates, printing, uninstall, ppa, canon

In an effort to use my printer, I installed a PPA but in the end, this PPA was not necessary. Now, this PPA causes an error when updates are loaded. 
The update error message is the following:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I looked over the web how to remove a ppa but the answers are too technical for my level of understanding.
I found this line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

but I don't know what should be put in place of the "whatever". 
On top of that, I can't even remember how I installed this PPA. I know I went to this page:

https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon/+packages

and somehow, followed the included instructions, without really knowing what I was doing.

According to some help pages I found, installed file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d should give me some hints:

```
  jockey.list                            nvbn-rm-ppa-precise.list
langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list       nvbn-rm-ppa-precise.list.save
langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list.save  precise-partner.list
michael-gruz-canon-precise.list        precise-partner.list.save
```

but I don't understand what to look for in this list of files. 
I suspect that the culprits is *michael-gruz-canon-precise.list*, but that doesn't help me much.

I hope I put all the necessary info here.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:michael-gruz/canon

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

See also:

- [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fix your problem with YPPA. Here, this will help you. Use y ppa to remove any duplicate ppa or fix ppa errors after installing it.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```